# how to ensure that a user can not redirect to another element in the child engine from within the parent engine

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have some engines mounted inside another engines as this engine is to be made a congregation of multiple child elements from various engines. This engine is finally mounted in the main app.
My routes are as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :Parent_Engine, :path  => "/foo" do
    match "/", :to=>"parent_engine#index"

    resources :parent_engine , :only=>[:show] do
      mount Engine1::Engine => '/engine1'
      mount Engine2::Engine => '/engine2'
    end
  end
end
```

Now when i wish to see an element from "engine1" i simply have a url as

```
/parent_engine/:id/engine1/object_type/:id
```

The trouble i am facing is that i need to stop a user from being able to access another object of engine1 by explicitly updating the url in the browser. Eg:

from:

```
/parent_engine/1/engine1/object_type/1
```

to:

```
/parent_engine/2/engine1/object_type/2
```

Also i can not put the check in the mounted engines as these are mounted seperately in the container app as well.
I just dont want the user to be able to be able to redirect to another object instance when inside the context of the parent engine.

Thanks and regards for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you try to do, but I suspect you may be able to use route constraints:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :Parent_Engine, :path  => "/foo" do
    match "/", :to=>"parent_engine#index"

    resources :parent_engine , :only=>[:show] do
      mount Engine1::Engine => '/engine1', :constraints => Engine1Contraint.new
      mount Engine2::Engine => '/engine2'
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can define `config/initializers/engine1_contraints.rb` with

```
class Engine1Contraint
  def matches?(request)
    request.path != 'something' || request.env['warden'].user == 'Admin'
  end
end
```

or whatever rules you need to adjust there, from the mother engine to control over the child engines.